# Should I use ANOVA to analyse this experiment?

Tags: anova, self-study, experiment-design

We performed an experiment on bacterial growth whereby optical density was recorded for three flasks of *E. coli* bacteria every 30 minutes for 4 hours. 2 flasks upon the 2 hour mark were inoculated with two different antibiotics, whilst the other served as a control.

Would a one-way ANOVA be appropriate in this case? Should I, for example, select two time points: one before adding the antibiotic, one after and do two separate ANOVAs?

I will be using class data so I will have 5 replicates for each time point.

Answer (score 1):

No, you shouldn't use a one-way ANOVA. Since you have multiple time points, your data are not independent. Since this is a HW question, I won't spell out the answers, but think about ways to take that lack of independence into account.

In part, the right answer will depend on what course this is homework for.